# Refetching data from server after a delete mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm new to graphQL. I'm creating a small post-sharing platform. After deleting a post, I want to refetch data from the backend server.
I have tried so many ways. Finally I found this method.
Is this the correct method to fetch data after a mutation?

```js
const [deletePostFunc,{loading}]=useMutation(DELETE_POST,{
  update(proxy,result){ },
    refetchQueries: ({ data }) => [
        {
          query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
          variables: {
            page:page,
            size:size
          },
        },
      ],
      awaitRefetchQueries: true,
    onError(err){
        console.log(err?.graphQLErrors[0]?.extensions.errors)
    },
    variables:{postId:post.id}
})
```

This is the Delete Post Mutation

```js
const DELETE_POST = gql`
    mutation ($postId:ID!){
        deletePost(postId:$postId)
    } 
`;
```

This is the Post Fetch Query

```
FETCH_POSTS_QUERY = gql`
    query getPosts($size:Int! $page:Int!){
        getPosts(size:$size page:$page){
            id
            body
            email
            createdAt 
        }
    }
`;
```